# React-Native Horizontal Scroll View Pagination: Preview Next Page/Card

Tags: react-native, pagination, scrollview, carousel, horizontalscrollview

I want to to a horizontal ScrollView with pagination enabled with one special requirement: each page (or card) is 90% of the container wide. The remaining 10% should be a preview of the next page.

It is possible to do this with ScrollView? Can I somehow specify the width of the pagination instead of taking the width of the container?

[image: Carousel]
(image taken from this similar question: [React Native Card Carousel view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37474552/react-native-card-carousel-view))

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can absolutely do that with `ScrollView` or, even better, `FlatList`. However, the really tricky part is the snapping effect. You can use props `snapToInterval` and `snapToAlignment` to achieve it (see [Vasil Enchev's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45478806/8412141)); unfortunately, these are iOS-only.

A co-worker and I created a plugin that answers this particular need. We ended up open-sourcing it, so it's all yours to try: [`react-native-snap-carousel`](https://github.com/archriss/react-native-snap-carousel/).

The plugin is now built on top of `FlatList` (versions >= 3.0.0), which is great to handle huge numbers of items. It provides **previews** (the effect you're after), **snapping effect** for iOS and Android, **parallax images**, **RTL support**, and more.

You can take a look at the [showcase](https://github.com/archriss/react-native-snap-carousel#showcase) to get a grasp of what can be achieved with it. Do not hesitate to share your experience with the plugin since we're always trying to improve it.

[image: react-native-snap-carousel archriss showcase]
[image: react-native-snap-carousel archriss aix]

---

Edit : [two new layouts](https://github.com/archriss/react-native-snap-carousel/#layouts-and-custom-interpolations) have been introduced in version `3.6.0` (one with a stack of cards effect and the other with a tinder-like effect). Enjoy!

[image: react-native-snap-carousel stack layout]
[image: react-native-snap-carousel tinder layout]

Comment: @AlfredAlfizoMosima Sure ;-) [Here is](https://snack.expo.io/@akyker20/react-native-snap-carousel-bug) a simple example.

Comment: trying to achieve something similar but with recyclerlistview.. FlatList has too many issues for me..

Comment: You're awesome guys.. Thanks for this great component. I was stuck with flatlist trying to get the current active item index for some animation related stuff. I tried all day but it was failing for large data sets. Snap Carousal gave perfect results. Thanks again.

Answer (score 46):

I spend a lot of time fighting with this until I figured it out so here is my solution if it helps someone.

https://snack.expo.io/H1CnjIeDb

Problem was all these were required and pagination should be turned off

```
horizontal={true}
decelerationRate={0}
snapToInterval={width - 60}
snapToAlignment={"center"}
```

Answer (score 13):

Use disableIntervalMomentum={ true } in your ScrollView. This will only allow the user to scroll one page at a time horizontally. Check official documents
https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#disableintervalmomentum

```
 <ScrollView 
  horizontal
  disableIntervalMomentum={ true } 
  snapToInterval={ width }
 >
  <Child 1 />
  <Child 2 />
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can pass a horizontal props to your scroll view:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#horizontal

And then you can create a view inside to specify your width requirements.

```
<ScrollView 
  ref={(snapScroll) => { this.snapScroll = snapScroll; }}
  horizontal={true} 
  decelerationRate={0}
  onResponderRelease={()=>{

   var interval = 300; // WIDTH OF 1 CHILD COMPONENT 

   var snapTo = (this.scrollingRight)? Math.ceil(this.lastx / interval) : 
    Math.floor(this.lastx / interval);
   var scrollTo = snapTo * interval;
   this.snapScroll.scrollTo(0,scrollTo);
  }}
  scrollEventThrottle={32}
  onScroll={(event)=>{
    var nextx = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x;
    this.scrollingRight = (nextx > this.lastx);
    this.lastx = nextx;
  }}
  showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false} 
  style={styles.listViewHorizontal}
  >

  {/* scroll-children here */}

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I have `horizontal={true} pagingEnabled={true}` as props in the ScrollView. But the "scroll view stops on multiples of the scroll view's size when scrolling"

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#pagingenabled

Comment: Also see this issue for help https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1362

Answer (score 3):

Here is example of simple scrollview pagination for bottom:

```
<ScrollView
......
onMomentumScrollEnd={event => {
   if (isScrollviewCloseToBottom(event.nativeEvent)) {
      this.loadMoreData();
   }
}}
</ScrollView>

.....
....

function isScrollviewCloseToBottom({
  layoutMeasurement,
  contentOffset,
  contentSize,
}) {
  const paddingToBottom = 20;
  return (
    layoutMeasurement.height + contentOffset.y >=
    contentSize.height - paddingToBottom
  );
}

......
....
```

same as we can use this for right pagination:

```
function isScrollviewCloseToRight({
  layoutMeasurement,
  contentOffset,
  contentSize,
}) {
  const paddingToRight = 10;
  return (
    layoutMeasurement.width + contentOffset.x >=
    contentSize.width - paddingToRight
  );
}
```

Hope it will helpful..!!

Answer (score 0):

You can look at `contentOffset` and `scrollTo` property of ScrollView . Logically what you can do is whenever the page changes(mostly when moved to next page) you can provide a extra offset of 10% or so as per your need so that the next item in the scrollview becomes visible .

Hope this helps, let me know if you need any extra details .