# React Native ScrollView with pagination + showing part of the next page

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ios

I'm trying to create an interface where cards are presented one at a time to the user. The user can scroll left and right in a paged fashion. I also want to view a small amount of the card to the left and the right of the current card, as a hint that there is more to see. A very rough example of this would be:

[image]

Current code is:

```
<ScrollView
   style={{width: Dimensions.get('window').width, height: 300}}
   horizontal={true}
   pagingEnabled={true}
   showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
   alwaysBounceHorizontal={false}
   automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}>
    <View style={{width: 200, height: 300}}></View>
    <View style={{width: 200, height: 300}}></View>
    <View style={{width: 200, height: 300}}></View>
 </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45489904/8412141) to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43212931/react-native-horizontal-scroll-view-pagination-preview-next-page-card/45489904#45489904) might help you.

To sum up, you absolutely can create this kind of layout with `ScrollView` or, even better, `FlatList`. However, there are two tricky parts:

- **The snapping effect**, for which you can use props [`snapToInterval`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#snaptointerval) and [`snapToAlignment`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#snaptoalignment). Unfortunately, these are iOS-only.
- **The animation of the inactive slides**, which needs a lot of custom logic.

A co-worker and I created a plugin that answers this particular need. We ended up open-sourcing it, so it's all yours to try: [`react-native-snap-carousel`](https://github.com/archriss/react-native-snap-carousel/).

The plugin is now built on top of `FlatList` (versions >= 3.0.0), which is great to handle huge numbers of items. It provides **previews** (the effect you're after), **snapping effect** for iOS and Android, **parallax images**, **RTL support**, and more.

You can take a look at the [showcase](https://github.com/archriss/react-native-snap-carousel#showcase) to get a grasp of what can be achieved with it. Do not hesitate to share your experience with the plugin since we're always trying to improve it.

[image: react-native-snap-carousel archriss showcase]
[image: react-native-snap-carousel archriss aix]

---

Edit : [two new layouts](https://github.com/archriss/react-native-snap-carousel/#layouts-and-custom-interpolations) have been introduced in version `3.6.0` (one with a stack of cards effect and the other with a tinder-like effect). Enjoy!

[image: react-native-snap-carousel stack layout]
[image: react-native-snap-carousel tinder layout]

Comment: All good but a long swipe scrolls multiple items, this differs from the `pagingEnabled` to `ScrollView`

Comment: Yes, some tweaks had to be made since `ScrollView` has [a whole bunch of limitations](https://github.com/archriss/react-native-snap-carousel/tree/flatlist#flatlist-and-scrollviews-limitations). Still, setting the prop `scrollEndDragDebounceValue` to `0` might help with that. You can also play with `ScrollView`'s prop [`decelerationRate`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#decelerationrate) (iOS only).

Comment: I think that version `3.2.1` is closer to what you were expecting. Note that I am going to work on implementing a custom scroller on top of the `FlatList` in order to better customize carousel's feeling and provide rich interactions.