# Horizontal paging: How to find which page that's currently active?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Here's my code to generate a paging scrollview in React-native:

```
        <ScrollView
          horizontal
          pagingEnabled
          onScrollEndDrag={this.handlePagerScroll}
          scrollsToTop={false}
          scrollEventThrottle={100}
          removeClippedSubviews={false}
          automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
          directionalLockEnabled
          showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        >
          { renderPageHere() }
        </ScrollView>
```

The code above is working.
Function `this.handlePagerScroll` which attached to `onScrollEndDrag` event is working too. The problem is that I can't determine which page that's currently active, since `onScrollEndDrag` has no event paremeter

I think to use simple math using value in `x` or `y` to no avail since I have no idea how to obtain them

Does anyone familiar with my problem and can offer me any solution?
Thank you

Comment: Why are you using ScrollView as you can use FlatList?

Comment: because I just follow this example here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43212931/react-native-horizontal-scroll-view-pagination-preview-next-page-card

Comment: It works for me, so I think it'll be okey

Comment: I have made a horizontal paging view using FlatList and identifying visible item in FlatList is fairly easy like this. 
<FlatList
          horizontal={true}
          pagingEnabled
          removeClippedSubviews={false}
          data={listData}
          onViewableItemsChanged={data => {
            this.viewableItem(data)
          }}
          renderItem={this.renderRow}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id}
        />

Comment: did it work for you?

Comment: it works! Thank you, if you can provide me an example as an answer, then I can close this thread.

Comment: AND also can you help me to make `onViewableItemsChanged` event only fired once after the page is done switching ? I have mine fires several time as I swipe the page

Comment: Never mind, I found out myself. It turns out, that I need to use `viewabilityConfig:  { waitForInteraction: true, viewAreaCoveragePercentThreshold: 95 }`

Comment: Did you use Flatlist?

Comment: I have posted the answer so it can help others, thanks

Comment: Can you also accept the answer please, thanks

Comment: Yes, I use flatList, just like your answer. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have made a horizontal paging view using FlatList and identifying visible item in FlatList is fairly easy like this.

```
<FlatList 
horizontal={true} 
pagingEnabled 
removeClippedSubviews={false} 
data={listData} 
onViewableItemsChanged={data => { this.viewableItem(data) }} renderItem={this.renderRow} 
keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id}
/>
```

**UPDATE**

As per issue posted on [GitHub](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/17408) and also mentioned by @DennyHiu

you can use

> viewabilityConfig={this.viewabilityConfig}

like this

```
this.viewabilityConfig = {
            itemVisiblePercentThreshold: 50,
            minimumViewTime: 1,
        };

<FlatList
  key={this.state.key}
  onViewableItemsChanged={this.handleViewableItemsChanged}
  viewabilityConfig={this.viewabilityConfig}
  data={this.state.timeline}
  renderItem={({item}) => {}}
 />
```